# Plotting a function (having different equations for different range of x) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using R and the ggplot2 package to draw several math functions on a single plot. Here is a minimal working example, plotting two simple equations in the -5 < x < 5 interval.

```
library(ggplot2)

### define math functions
line1 <- function(x) {
  x^2
}
line2 <- function(x) {
  x^3
}

### build plot
f1 =
  #make basic plot
  ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-5,5)), aes(x)) +

  # draw line 1
  stat_function(fun=line1, geom="line", colour="red") +

  # draw line 2
  stat_function(fun=line2, geom="line", colour="blue") +

print(f1)
```

So far so good: both line are plotted. Now comes my issue. I would like to plot each equation in a specific interval of x values. (eg, line 1 for x < 0 and line 2 for x > 0). I don't know how to do that.

I've tried to set different xlimits in each stat_funcion(), but it's not working. Probably it's not possible to define any xlim within a stat_function().

Alternatively, I've tried to include if statements when defining the functions, but it's not working either. (And possibly it's not even the best approch..)

```
### define math functions
line1 <- function(x) {
  if (x < 0) {
    x^2 } else {

    }
}
line2 <- function(x) {
  if (x > 0) {
    x^3 } else {

    }
}

### build plot
f1 =
  #make basic plot
  ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-5,5)), aes(x)) +

  # draw line 1
  stat_function(fun=line1, geom="line", colour="red") +

  # draw line 2
  stat_function(fun=line2, geom="line", colour="blue") +

print(f1)
```

I'll be very grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: Adding a `data` parameter with a different `x` range to each `stat_function` doesn't do it... I can only think that you have to evaluate your function over the ranges you want into a dataframe and pass that to `geom_line`

Comment: Yes, I tried that approach without success. I don't know if I misspelled my input or if that's not the good method.

Comment: You could also rewrite your functions to return NA out of your desired range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a decorating function that returns NA if outside a given range:

```
rwrap=function(f,xmin,xmax){ff=function(x){y=f(x);y[x>xmax]=NA;y[x<xmin]=NA;y}}
```

Now some data, and an example:

```
d=data.frame(x=c(-5,5))
ggplot(d,aes(x=x))+stat_function(fun=rwrap(line1,0,5),geom="line",col="blue") + stat_function(fun=rwrap(line2,-5,0),geom="line",col="red")
```

If you've not seen decorating functions like that then a little explanation. It basically wraps your function in some code, returning a similar function.

```
> line1(-5:5)
 [1] 25 16  9  4  1  0  1  4  9 16 25
> rwrap(line1,0,3)(-5:5)
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA  0  1  4  9 NA NA
```

You can save the wrapped function if you want:

```
> w2 = rwrap(line2,0,3)
> w2(-5:5)
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA  0  1  8 27 NA NA
```

In the example above I've just done everything in one.

[image: two plots]

Comment: Great solutions: perfectly working and very clean! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I wonder if its worth asking Hadley W for an xrange option here?

Comment: Why not. I think it would be a quite useful option. Should a post a feature request on [ggplot2 google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ggplot2) or is there a better place?

Comment: Try the issue section of the ggplot2 github repository.